# Javascript - How to fire an event handler immediately rather than queue it

Tags: javascript

Usually when a javascript event is fired from the code (as far as I know) the event handler is added to a queue, and will only be run after the current code.
(see, e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Now, I have a call to `element.blur()`, and I want to run the function associated to the blur event imediately, and just after that would execution resume.

I could just call the function, but it was defined by a framework (ionic) and I do not want to mess with its internals, so ideally, I would retrieve the function programatically rather than know its name.

Is is possible? How?

Comment: i agree, cant help much without seeing some code here

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may call the associated function directly. However, therefore it needs to be in scope:

```
function onblur(){
    this.style.color="blue";
}

document.getElementById("someelem").addEventListener("blur",onblur);
```

If you want to call it directly:

```
onblur.call(document.getElementById("someelem"));
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! In my case, however, the function was defined (in some unknown line) by a framework (ionic). So i'd probably need an extra step to retrieve the function.